# Designing a flyback converter for 12V Input to 120V Output with LT Spice. Are these reverse voltage spikes normal

Tags: transformer, ltspice, schottky, spike

[image: Voltage across the primary inductor]

With this setup, I'm getting some periodic voltage spikes on the primary and secondary inductor (secondary spikes to around 2.7kV). The output shows the constant ~120V I want. Are those voltage spikes normal? If yes, how do I counteract them? With a schottky diode in parallel to the given inductor?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your design is not a flyback converter: -

[image]

You need to fix this then see what the flyback voltage looks like: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html).

You will find that when you have done this correctly, the flyback voltage will be naturally positive. You will also find that having K = 1 is not possible in real life and that the inevitable leakage inductance (K = 0.97 for instance) of the primary will splash a big back-emf that you will likely cure with a diode snubber.

Anyway, fix your circuit first and present a new back-emf waveform.

One further thing, name the nodes you are probing so everyone can make sense of your new node names (rather than undecipherable node numbers) AND, add a 6 kΩ (ish) load to your output to prevent the circuit entering discontinuous conduction mode and/or the output voltage being unstable.

Comment: that looks much better now, thank you. For said diode snubber i would use a normal rectifier diode in series with a high valued resistor?

Comment: Resistor in parallel with capacitor; both in series with a diode. Try and use a high-speed diode to avoid losses. You are simulating so you will see immediately why the capacitor helps and, the resistor is in parallel to discharge it before the next cycle. I think, if you want, you can maybe show the output waveform results after changing the circuit as I instructed but, make sure you put it at the end of your question and call it an edited section @P4r4Lys3d

Comment: That makes sense. How do i chose the capacitor capacitance? Over the eneregy stored in the primary inductor at max current? And what about the resistor? @Andy aka

Comment: The capacitor is chosen to limit the nasty part of the flyback voltage to acceptable levels when the MOSFET turns off thus, preventing an overly excessive drain source voltage. The resistor has to be low enough so that that capacitor is discharged nearly totally between clock cycles. If you simulate you can fudge values until it looks about right.

Comment: Bear in mind that there will be what I call "good" flyback voltage at the primary and this is due to the secondary voltage reflecting back to the primary; the more you try and kill the good flyback the more headaches you have. In other words don't try and clamp the primary or the output voltage will reduce too much.

Comment: Understood, i will try that out, thank you! @Andy aka

Answer (score 0):

They are from leakage inductance in the transformer.

You can slow down the mosfet turn-off rate (will severely affect efficiency) or preferably add a clamp ( zener etc)

Comment: so that would be a resistor and a zener diode in series parallel to the inductor? Would a schottky diode also work out for filtering the reverse voltages? Because the breakdown voltage would be too small? What makes the zener diode perform better in this case?

Comment: `They are from leakage inductance in the transformer.` There's no leakage in the simulation i.e. coupling factor is given as 1.